# Create an alias for a Map specialization in Dart

Tags: dart

Ideally I'm looking for something like :

```
typedef Json = Map<String, dynamic>;
```

From what I understand, this language feature is under review [typedef for simple type aliases](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/2626) with ETA Q1'19

But for a immediate alternative, what would be the simplest way to "extend" a Map in Dart ? All the solutions I could find are quite old and look overkill. At the end I just want an alias for my Map.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you really don't want to wait, you could make your own class that wraps an existing `Map` and implements just the methods you need.  If you need your class to actually be a `Map` type, you can do `class MyMap with MapMixin<String, int> implements Map<String, dynamic>`.

Comment: This feature is being implemented and tracked here: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/65

Answer (score 1):

Dart 2.13

1. Update analysis_options.yaml

```yaml
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - nonfunction-type-aliases
```

2. Run

```
flutter run --enable-experiment=nonfunction-type-aliases
```

Comment: More info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66847006/how-do-i-use-type-aliases-typedefs-also-non-function-in-dart