# How do I use Type Aliases / Typedefs (also non-function) in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have known **function typedefs** in Dart for a long time. They are also explained in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12545762/6509751).

Now, I have heard about **non-function type aliases** (or non-function typedefs) coming to Dart.

---

I am wondering two things:

- What exactly are (non-function) typedefs in Dart?
- How do I use them (in my Flutter project)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Generalized type aliases / typedefs in Dart

You can view the [feature specification for *Generalized type alisases*](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/2.13/nonfunction-type-aliases/feature-specification.md) for the full design document.

I want to preface this by pointing out that Dart used to only support typedefs **for functions**. The **new generalized** feature supports ***typedefs for any type***.

```dart
typedef JsonMap = Map<String, dynamic>;

JsonMap parseJsonMap(String input) => json.decode(input) as JsonMap;
```

This is especially useful when you have multiple generic types (type parameters) that cause long type names that are tedious to type, for example `Map<ScaffoldFeatureController<SnackBar, SnackBarClosedReason>, SnackBar>`. This can now be simplified using a type alias:

```dart
typedef ScaffoldSnackBarMap = Map<ScaffoldFeatureController<SnackBar, SnackBarClosedReason>, SnackBar>;
```

#### Syntax

If not clear from the above examples, this is the syntax for type alisases / typedefs:

```
'typedef' identifier typeParameters? '=' type ';'
```

This means that you always need to start with the `typedef` keyword followed by your desired identifier, e.g. `FooTypeDef`. After that, you can add type parameters, e.g. `Foo<K, V>`. The last step is adding the `=` symbol followed by the actual type you want to create an alias for. This can be **any type**, i.e. a class, primitive type, function type, or w/e. Do not forget the `;` at the end ;)

```dart
// Type parameters / generic types in typedef.
typedef Foo<K, V> = Map<K, V>;

// Type alias for regular types.
typedef Bar = Widget;
// As well as primitive types.
typedef Baz = int;

// Function types are also supported.
typedef FooFunction<T, R> = R Function(T param);
```

#### Deprecating names

Additionally, you can use `typedef`s for *any class* names. Say you want to rename your class from `Provider` to `Pod` because you think the former is too verbose. If you are maintaining a package, this would be a *breaking change*. With the new generalized type aliases, you can simply rename your class and create a type alias that you deprecate:

```dart
class NewClassName<T> {}

@Deprecated("Use NewClassName instead")
typedef OldClassName<T> = NewClassName<T>;
```

Note that this example and the one above are taken from the [proposed CHANGELOG entry](https://dart-review.googlesource.com/c/sdk/+/192948/2/CHANGELOG.md) for the feature.

### How to use them

The feature will be *shipped by default* with **Dart 2.13** but is currently still experimental. I will cover how to use it in both ways; the experimental method can be removed later on.

#### Dart 2.13

As I mentioned previously, the feature will be enabled *by default* starting with Dart 2.13. If you currently have Dart 2.13 installed already (you can use `dart --version` to check it for example), you can use this method. Otherwise, you should refer to the *Experimental support* section below.

In your `pubspec.yaml`, you need to define the **lower bound** on your Dart SDK constraint to be greater than or equal to `2.13.0`:

```yaml
environment:
  dart: '>=2.13.0 <3.0.0'
```

#### Experimental support

In your Flutter project (or any other Dart project), you **currently** need to enable them as [an experiment](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/ec51b7a866275e84da091c718b7dd172fffcdfe1/tools/experimental_features.yaml#L109). It means that they are hidden behind a feature flag.

---

Experimental Dart features can be configured using `analysis_options.yaml`. You can simply create an [`analysis_options.yaml` file](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#the-analysis-options-file) in the root of your project directory and add the following lines:

```yaml
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - nonfunction-type-aliases
```

Now, you need to also enable the experiment when you **run** (or build) your app:

```
flutter run --enable-experiment=nonfunction-type-aliases
```

To make sure that you can use this feature, use the `master` channel (`flutter channel master` when using Flutter).

Comment: You can track the implementation progress here: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44951