# How to define concrete type from generic in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make multiple Controller Types foo multiple Models for use with Provider in Flutter.

This is my Code:

```dart
//generic controller
class ModelController<E extends HiveObject> extends ChangeNotifier {
  Box<E> _db;

  ModelController(Box<E> db) {
    _db = db;
  }

  // getters
  List<E> get all => _db.values;

  // create
  void add(E item) {
    _db.add(item);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void update(E item) {
    item.save();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // delete
  void delete(E item) {
    item.delete();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class PacketController extends ModelController<Packet>{
  PacketController(Box<Packet> db) : super(db);

}
```

The code for class PacketController is the only way I found to create a concrete type from a generic one.

**Question:Is there a better way for this?**

Shortly, I am looking for something like typedef in c++:

```
typedef IntVector std::vector<int>
```

Comment: Dart (as of version 2.12) supports creating only `typedef`s to functions.  However, the upcoming Dart 2.13 release will add support for general `typedef`s as an opt-in, experimental feature. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66847006/

Comment: What are you trying to do that requires this? For example, what are you using `var controller = PacketController(box);` for that prohibits you from using `var controller = ModelController<Packet>(box);`? Or is this merely a question about conciseness?

Comment: I find PacketController easier to read than ModelController<Packet> and I was wondering if it can be defined in one line, instead of creating new Class by extension.

Comment: The question is now becoming irrelevant for my project, since I have to implement other methods inside the controller class, but i would still like to find the answer for future reference.